Is `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer` expected to work with registries other than confluent platform registry?
I've seen that there are many schema registry implementations supporting avro format.
Some of them are:

Apicurio Registry

AWS Glue Schema Registry

Google Cloud Schema Registry

Redhat Service registry


My question is:
Is io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer (and KafkaAvroDeserializer), which performs schema registry
validation, supposed to be compatible with the above registries? Is there any common specification shared between them?

The Apicurio one is the sane as RedHat registry and has a Confluent mode/endpoint I think, but there's no true specification. Each project has their own Java classes for Kafka (not sure about pubsub)

@OneCricketeer I now see that in apicurio they claim to support confluent schema registry api. Found this: "The Registry REST API is compatible with the Confluent schema registry REST API, which includes support for Apache Avro, Google Protocol buffers, and JSON Schema artifact types. Applications using Confluent client libraries can use Apicurio Registry as a drop-in replacement instead."

For Glue, migration is necessary https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/schema-registry-integrations-migration.html
